# Does anyone else find that using stackexchange generates lots of superficial questions in their own imagination?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone else find that using stackexchange generates lots of superficial questions in their own imagination?

I should leave for good, so good luck :-)

Apologies if everyone hated these accounts :-(

Comment: I haven’t had that experience, no.

Comment: ah, it may well be peculiar to me. my apologies @DanBron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sites not only suggest to users questions of various quality, but they also offer users ways to improve their practice

1. asking questions,
2. answering them and
3. judging both questions and answers posted by others.

Please stick around. I enjoy reading your posts. We all need practice asking good questions. We can all improve our posts.

Comment: yeah i'll stay a bit longer, thanks Frank

Comment: btw, i appreciate your contribution here, also, and your enthusiasm for learning philosophy despite - i assume - not wanting any academic position. thanks Frank, good luck with the site.

Comment: @another_name Thank you! I am also retired so an academic position would not be of much benefit to me - or anyone else. Philosophy is something I enjoy reading. It is good to do that with others and this SE site provides that communal context.

Comment: i believe i've trapped at undergraduate limbo forever ha

Comment: Glad, very glad, to know that you'll stay. Best - Geoff